# How to delete user and host ansible?

Tags: php, mysql, ansible

I currently have an Ansible playbook installing mySql and a few other things. During the mySQL role, I have all the root users and their hosts getting set up correctly. However after the playbook finishes successfully, one of the users (root@keenan-virtualbox) is still present after I try to remove him from the table. I don't want to remove that account excplictly and want it to work on many different machines. As such, $ansible_hostname should be the host I want to remove. Below is my main.yml from the mysql task and the mysql.user table after it gets completed.

```
   ---
    - name: MySQL | Set debconf vars
    action: raw sudo echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 
    $mysql_root_password | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
    tags: mysql

    - name: MySQL | Set debconf vars
      action: raw sudo echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $mysql_root_password | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
  tags: mysql

    - name: Add the OS specific variables
      include_vars: "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"

    - name: Install the mysql packages in Redhat derivatives
  yum: name={{ item }} state=installed
  with_items: mysql_pkgs
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'

- name: Install the mysql packages in Debian derivatives
  apt: name={{ item }} state=installed update_cache=yes
  with_items: mysql_pkgs
  environment: env
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: Copy the my.cnf file 
  template: src=my.cnf.{{ ansible_os_family }}.j2 dest={{ mysql_conf_dir }}/my.cnf
  notify: 
   - restart mysql

- name: Create the directory /etc/mysql/conf.d
  file: path=/etc/mysql/conf.d state=directory
  notify:
   - restart mysql

- name: Start the mysql services Redhat
  service: name={{ mysql_service }} state=started enabled=yes

- name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
  ignore_errors: yes
  mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_db_pass }}
  with_items:
   - $ansible_hostname
   - 127.0.0.1
   - ::1
   - localhost 
- name: copy .my.cnf file with root password credentials
  template: src=.my.cnf.j2 dest=~/.my.cnf mode=0600

- name: ensure anonymous users are not in the database
  mysql_user: name='' host={{ item }} state=absent
  with_items:
   - localhost
   - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"

- name: remove the test database
  mysql_db: name=test state=absent

- name: Create the database's
  mysql_db: name={{ item.name }} state=present
  with_items: mysql_db
  when: mysql_db|lower() != 'none'

- name: Create the database users
  mysql_user: name={{ item.name }}  password={{ item.pass|default("") }}
                priv={{ item.priv|default("*.*:ALL") }} state=present host={{ item.host | default("localhost") }}
  with_items: mysql_users
  when: mysql_users|lower() != 'none'

- name: Delete ansible host root user
  mysql_user: name=root host={{ ansible_hostname }} state=absent


- name: Restart mysql
  action: service name=mysql state=restarted enabled=true



--------------------------------------------------------------------------


+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user          | host              | password                                  |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root          | localhost         | *3F9DF5A32114E05C12C50A83EAE02991016C917B |
| root          | keenan-VirtualBox |                                           |
| root          | 127.0.0.1         | *3F9DF5A32114E05C12C50A83EAE02991016C917B |
| root          | ::1               | *3F9DF5A32114E05C12C50A83EAE02991016C917B |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost      | *726DD22D744226797C5E47F531F32DE43F595B5B |
| root          | $ansible_hostname | *3F9DF5A32114E05C12C50A83EAE02991016C917B |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the [mysql_user module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/database/mysql/mysql_user.py#L271)- the problem is that your hostname has a hyphen in it, and the module isn't quoting the user and host, so the DROP USER executed by the module is likely failing silently (ie, no match). Just out of curiosity, have you tried this play on a non-hyphenated host?

Comment: No, I have not tried it on a non-hyphenated host yet. I'm going to remove the hyphen from the hostname an run the play again.

Comment: Removing the hyphen from the hostname seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help.